# html inline node with text siblings misplacement

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I have the following html:

```
<span as="0" style="display: block; -webkit-user-select: text; ">
"[TEXT]"
<span id="as_cursor" style="padding: 0px; margin:0px; width: 0px;"></span>
"[TEXT]"
</span>
```

I use the inner span as a marker from which to later get the coordinates with jquery.offset(). When this span coincides with end of line (as rendered on screen, no eol character in the actual text) the inner span is rendered at the beginning (top left) of the outer element, thus giving an erroneous offset of (0,0).

Is there any way I can get around this behaviour? At present, only chrome and mozilla compatibility is required.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't get the offset is because span elements are inline. To fix this problem add the following code to the head section of your HTML page:

```
<style>
    .offsetFixed {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #outerSpan {
        display: block;
        -webkit-user-select: text;
    }

    #as_cursor {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
</style>
```

In addition make the following modifications to your HTML:

```
<span class="offsetFixed" id="outerSpan" as="0">"[TEXT]"
    <span class="offsetFixed" id="as_cursor"></span>"[TEXT]"
</span>
```

Then you can use jQuery to get the correct offset:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offset = $("#as_cursor").offset();
    alert(JSON.stringify(offset));
});
```

Comment: Actually by design it does have to be inline, as it has to act as a marker without disrupting the normal flow of the text nodes surrounding it, if I use inline-block (already tried!) I get a new-line after the inner span. I do get a correct offset() value if the inner span doesn't coincide with a rendered end of line, it's just at the end.
I think it has to do with whitespace treatment, but none of the css white-space values helps...

Comment: Okay, just for the sake of getting this out of the way - inline elements do not have explicit dimensions, and they don't wrap; block elements do have explicit dimensions, and they do wrap; inline-block elements also do have explicit dimensions, but they don't wrap. Thus there's no reason you should get a newline after the inner span. Anyhow, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The inner span is a marker in a block of text for where the cursor last was, that way I can modify the structure of the span and get back to the insertion point at a later time; and yes I realize the width=0 isn't necessary. If I understood the reason behind the behaviour, I wouldn't be asking ;-)
I "sort of" solved it by using a placeholder character inside the inner span (&zwnj;) and magically it behaved. Thanks for your effort  anyway.